# Continuity With Piecewise Functions and Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, piecewise-continuity

Can someone explain how I would do this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow c^+}f(x)$$
Where will  $\sin c=\cos c ?$ Or better.
$\tan c=1$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are both continuous functions, so the only place your function $f(x)$ might *not* be continuous is at the point $x=c$, when it switches from being $\sin x$ to $\cos x$.

To ensure $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$, we need
$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=f(c)$$
i.e.,
$$\lim_{x \to c^-} f(x)=\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x) = f(c).$$
Now you should be able to fill in what those two limits are and what $f(c)$ is, based on the definition of $f(x)$. What does that tell you about $c$?